# It is possible to check if this route return valid page?

Tags: angular

I use Angular 5 with localize-router. Localize-router doesn't support path without language prefix (only main page) so I try to write component to do that. So in router I has 2 component:

```
{
    path: '404',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundExceptionComponent
}
```

If route doesn't match any route I push this into `NotFoundExceptionComponent` where I want decide - it should be redirect into a other page or 404 page.

For example when I has path:
`www.example.com/test`
I want dredirect it into:
`www.excample.com/en/test`
but if somebody write:
`www.excample.com/testttt`
or
`www.excample.com/en/testttt`
I should redirect into 404 page.

I wrote a method that I trigger:

```
public redirectIntoCorrectPath() {
    this.redirectUrl = this.localize.translateRoute(this.location.path()).toString();
}
```

but now I need to check - is `this.redirectUrl` valid or trigger another `NotFoundExceptionComponent` action. If is valid - redirect into this page, if isn't valid, redirect into 404.

Is any method in Angular to detect where this URL redirect a user? To `**` or not?

Now I has only one idea to create singleton and detect if redirect one after another is too quick or has common element (one is included in another) and then redirect user into 404, but I look for better solution.

Comment: what's the difference between NotFoundPage and NotFoundExceptionPage? isn't it not found for both?

Comment: NotFoundComponent display custom error page when NotFoundExceptionComponent decide where I should redirect a user

Comment: Have you tried a "route guard"?  They are like a routing middle-ware whereby you can cancel routing or redirect based on logic.  Check it out... https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: "Localize-router doesn't support path without language prefix " what about `alwaysSetPrefix` option + refresh language (set lang with current lang) after app is loaded ?

Comment: @Gilsdav - I tried to used alwaysSetPrefix but I don't have any idea how to refresh language after app is loaded?

Comment: if you put "alwaysSetPrefix" will allow you to not have prefix but I have i mind that if you change the lang, localize-router will automaticaly put it in url. You can try something like this : `this.localize.changeLanguage(this.localize.parser.currentLang || this.localize.parser.defaultLang);` in ngOnInit of your AppComponent

Comment: I add my answer for this but this doesn't work with lazy loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me at this moment with router config as in my question.

```
public redirectIntoCorrectPath() {
    let control = false;

    // This function look for element in router & set control=true if element is found
    function controlUrlInRouter(obj, redirect) {
        try {
            obj.forEach(line => {
                if (!control) {
                    if (line.children) {
                        controlUrlInRouter(line.children, redirect);
                    } else {
                        if (line.path && line.path.length > 0 && redirect.indexOf(line.path) > -1) {
                            control = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    if (this.localizeParser.getLocationLang(this.location.path())) {
        // If element has language in URL and is not found -> redirect them into /404
        this.router.navigate([this.localizeService.translateRoute('/404')]);
    } else {
        // If URL doesn't has any language in URL we need more investigation

        // Generate new URL from actual information
        this.redirectUrl = this.localizeService.translateRoute(this.location.path()).toString();

        // Test this new URL (in result we update control variable)
        controlUrlInRouter(this.router.config, this.redirectUrl);

        if (control) {
            // If we found any element in router, we redirect into this page
            this.router.navigate([this.redirectUrl]);
        } else {
            // If we doesn't found any element in router, we redirect into /404
            this.router.navigate([this.localizeService.translateRoute('/404')]);
        }
    }
}
```